# wait an answer after post request python

Tags: python, sockets, server, python-requests

I am developing a server that acts as a bridge, I send him a request and then I send it again to an api, 
when I am turning this code with a localhost it works, I am getting an answer from the api. 
but when I am turning it with my server, I don't get any response. 
I think it depends on the waiting time, but I put sleep to 10 seconds and still no answer. 
Any idea?

```
def do_POST(self):

    print( "incomming http: ", self.path )

    content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data
    post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself

    #print(str(post_data))
    print("Got data.")

    response = bytes("Data Received.", "utf-8")
    self.send_response(200)

    self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(response)))
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(response) #send response

    test_name = "Jhon Doe"
    respserver = getId(test_name)
    try :
        print("sending to the other server..")
        idname = int(respserver)
        msg = post_data.decode("utf-8")
        js = json.loads(msg)

        respserver = sendIntRR(idname, js)
        print("waiting a response")
        sleep(1)
        print("Api : ", respserver)

    except :
        print("ExternalId : ", test_name)
        print(respserver)
```

the request is sent from here :

```
def sendIntRR (id : int, msg : str) -> str:
   url = apiurl + "collect/" + str(id)
   querystring = {"period":"300000","filter":"3","returnList":"True"}

   payload = msg
   headers = {
     'authorization': bearerClient,
     'content-type': "application/json",
     'cache-control': "no-cache",
     }

   response = requests.api.request('post', url, data=payload, headers=headers,params=querystring, json=None, verify=False)

   return(response.text)
```

What I get in the servers terminal :

```
sending to the other server..
ExternalId :  Jhon Doe
8
```

Thanks a lot, G.B

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer was the sleep, once I remove the sleep, that worked, don't know how to explain it but works now